# Как составить регулярное выражение для preg_replace, чтобы любой абзац без тегов обернуть в теги?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вот пример текста:

```
Каждый веб-разработчик знает, что такое текст-«рыба». Текст этот, несмотря на название, не имеет никакого отношения к обитателям водоемов. Используется он веб-дизайнерами для вставки на интернет-страницы и демонстрации внешнего вида контента, просмотра шрифтов, абзацев, отступов и т.д.

<h3>Конечно, возникают некоторые вопросы.</h3>

Самым известным «рыбным» текстом является знаменитый Lorem ipsum. Считается, что впервые его применили в книгопечатании еще в XVI веке. Своим появлением Lorem ipsum обязан древнеримскому философу Цицерону, ведь именно из его трактата «О пределах добра и зла» средневековый книгопечатник вырвал отдельные фразы и слова, получив текст-«рыбу», широко используемый и по сей день.

И даже с языками, использующими латинский алфавит, могут возникнуть небольшие проблемы: в различных языках те или иные буквы встречаются с разной частотой, имеется разница в длине наиболее распространенных слов.
```

Я написал такую регулярку:

```
^<h3>.*<\/h3>$
```

Но она цепляет все заголовки 3 уровня. Если добавить в начало символ "!", то тогда вообще ни чего не будет. [Вот](https://regex101.com/r/Dfk1kh/1) ссылка на regex101.

Comment: у вас это просто кусок текста как есть, или он находится внутри некого html документа?

Comment: Это кусок текста как есть, он не находится ни в каком документе. Я это всё вытащил из XML. Там было так. Теперь вот мне нужно обернуть все абзацы в <p>...</p>.

Comment: Используйте XSLT для преобразования XML в HTML, там и пропишите, чтобы текст был заключен в теги.

Comment: Ни разу ещё не сталкивался с XSLT. Интересно будет протестировать))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать регулярное выражение `^\s*([^<][^\r\n]+)$` - оно выделит все строки, которые начинаются не с символа `<`, игнорируя пробелы в начале. Далее останется лишь заменить текст, например, на `<p>$1</p>`. `$1` здесь - это первая (индексация здесь идет с единицы) группа, "пойманная" регулярным выражением в круглые скобки. Т.е. строка символов, не начанающаяся с `<`

Comment: Сработало. Только последний абзац выделился некорректно. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. https://regex101.com/r/Dfk1kh/2

Comment: попробуйте так: ^\s*([^<\r\n]+)$